# Extracting email id from a line

Tags: java, regex

Consider the following lines :

1. My email id is xyz@mail.com
2. Note my mail id, xyz@mail.com, so you can send a mail.

From these 2 sentences, I need to extract only the mail id. The mail id can exist in any place of the line. I used the following regex : \s.+@{1}.+.com

But for the above 2 sentences, it matches the following. This is not my expected result. :

1. email id is xyz@mail.com
2. Note my mail id, xyz@mail.com

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what should be the output, clearly?

Comment: Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using. There are a number of related questions on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bemail%5D+%5Bregex%5D+extract , which may also help.

Comment: @revo output should be just the email id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following regex to match almost all kind of email addresses

```
\b[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b
```

check [regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/dK6fY4) with explanations

Answer (score 1):

Some simple example

```
(.*)(\s)(.+@{1}.+.com)
```

so first parts 1`(.*)` and 2`(\s)` going to last space occurrence befor searched email 3`(.+@{1}.+.com)`

Test:

Replacing with Notepad++

**Find what:** (.*)(\s)(.+@{1}.+.com)

**Replace with:** +\1+\2+\3+

**Input:** My email id is xyz@mail.com

**Result:** +My email id is+ +xyz@mail.com+

This way you know that `\3` contain your email

**Disadvantages**:

If email is placed as first word in line this expression will not work

If email has something different than whitespace before it then this sign will be included in email address (this is consequence of asker email regex expression design)

Play with different cases and find best solution what suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "practical" implementation of RFC 5322 from  http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

```
>>> import re
>>> email = re.compile("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?")
>>> email.search('My email id is xyz@mail.com').group(0)
'xyz@mail.com'
>>> email.search('Note my mail id, xyz@mail.com, so you can send a mail').group(0)
'xyz@mail.com'
```

Comment: Thanks Robert for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
\<[^ ]+@{1}.+.com
```

The problem with your suggestion is, that regex' are greedy. `.+` catches the biggest match it can find, which is the whole line up to `.com`.

With `\<` you match the beginning of a word (needed if your email address has e.g. quotation marks around it), then `[^ ]+` matches everything except a whitespace, i.e. it prevents the greedy behavior of the regex.

Note that depending on the language your actually using (which you didn't specify), notation might be a little bit different (or not even available).

Comment: Thanks pfnuesel. But some how it did not work in Java. I will try again though.